# Displaying item only in specific category

Tags: php

on my database i have a category, how do I display a specific category only to be display on my php page ?

```
<?
            include("conn.php");
            $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                if(@$count % 2==0){
        ?>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="1000px">
<?php } ?>


            <td width="500"><img src="gambar/<?=$row['Gambar']?>" />
                <br><b><?=$row['product_name']?></b><br />
                    <?=$row['description_name']?><br />
                    Price:<big style="color:green">
                        RM<?=$row['price']?></big><br /><br />
```

the code above display all the item in the database.

Comment: add where condition in query to filter what you want *select * from products where category="dfdfdfdf"*

Comment: `select * from products WHERE category="Add reqd category here"`

Comment: @mickmackusa i'm sorry bro , search real hard just now to find my solution just seem like i can't find the keyword , i'm really new into php.

Comment: @undefined_variable thanks bro its working now !

Comment: @NaQiudinFadzil It is no crime to be new.  Being new means you are daring to grow.  Please always research heavily through SO and the internet before asking a question, the answers are (99.999999999999% of the time) already out there.  I have been using this site for years, and I have only managed to ask 3 questions because every question I can dream up (bar 3) has already been asked and answered on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `where` condition in query to filter Your result

```
 select * from products where category='books'
```

Comment: `"select * from products"` their query is already inside double quotes. Telling them to use `where category="books"` will fail.

Comment: nice catch @Fred-ii- thank you

Comment: always a pleasure